# VBA Excel 2013 Format Function changes Date

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

The following line of code changes not only the format of date, it also changes the value of the date. Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Code:

```
rng.Cells(intStartRow, rng.Columns.Count + 1) = _
Format(rng.Cells(intStartRow, rng.Columns.Count + 1).Value, "mmm-yy")
```

Value of  `rng.Cells(intStartRow, rng.Columns.Count + 1).Value` before executing the code:

[image]

Value of  `rng.Cells(intStartRow, rng.Columns.Count + 1).Value` after executing the code:

[image]

Comment: The `Format` procedure converts the date to a string. Writing it back to the cell converts it to a date by guessing the format (which is no properly done since the year is now on 2 digits). To keep it as a string, you could add a quote in front: `Cells(...).Value = "'" & Format(...) `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to convert to an actual date and change the displayed format, use:

```
With rng.Cells(intStartRow, rng.Columns.Count + 1)
   .Value = CDate(.Value)
   .NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it happens is that the date information is stored internally as decimal number and is displayed with the date format applied to the cell.
In your code you change the date information to a string as the result of the function `Format()` is always a string.
A soultion to solve the problem is suppliey by Rory